# using custom java classes with JPype: package not callable error

Tags: java, python, jpype

I'm trying to get a very simple example of using JPype (Version:
0.5.4.6) to instantiate a custom java class from within Python.  It
loosely follows an example:
http://hustleplay.wordpress.com/2010/02/18/jpype-tutorial/ and is
related to:
[JPype Headaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752371/jpype-headaches)

here's the python code (in /Users/me/jpypeTest/testjpype.py):

```
from jpype import *
cpopt="-Djava.class.path=%s" % ("/Users/me/jpypeTest")
startJVM(getDefaultJVMPath(),"-ea",cpopt)
print "JVM path:",getDefaultJVMPath()
print "classpath:",cpopt
java.lang.System.out.println("Hello World!!")
testPkg = JPackage('pkg')
Test = testPkg.Test
Test.speak("hi")
shutdownJVM()
```

and here's the java code (in /Users/me/jpypeTest/pkg/Test.java):

```
package pkg;
public class Test {
    private String msg;

    public Test() {
        msg = "nothing so far...";
    }

    public static void speak(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

compiled using:

```
javac Test.java
```

to produce /Users/me/jpypeTest/pkg/Test.class without errors
(I have also tried putting Test.class in working directory)

running the python code gives:

```
> python testjpype.py 
JVM path: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/JavaVM
classpath: -Djava.class.path=/Users/me/jpypeTest
Hello World!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testjpype.py", line 9, in <module>
    Test.speak("hi")
  File "/Users/me/dev/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jpype/_jpackage.py", line 53, in __call__
    raise TypeError, "Package "+self.__name+" is not Callable"
TypeError: Package pkg.Test.speak is not Callable
```

System is a mac running Mavericks with:

```
> java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

> javac -version
javac 1.7.0_45

> python --version
Python 2.7.5

> python -c 'import sys;print("%x" % sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize > 2**32)'
('7fffffffffffffff', True)
```

A JPype method for listing the imported java classes would also be very useful

Many thanks for looking at this!

Comment: Did you get solution to this?

Comment: I'm afraid not, abandoned long ago

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue appears to be that accessing an attribute of a JPackage class returns a JPackage class when what you really want is a JClass.  Changing the testjpype.py to be this worked for me:

```
from jpype import *
cpopt="-Djava.class.path=%s" % ("/Users/me/jpypeTest")
startJVM(getDefaultJVMPath(),"-ea",cpopt)
java.lang.System.out.println("Hello World!!")
Test = JClass('pkg.Test')
Test.speak("hi")
shutdownJVM()
```

Comment: appreciated.  I can't validate anymore because it's been too long since I asked original question.